# VB.NET Using Combobox to pull data from MS Access DataBase and fill the textbox from Data

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox

VB.NET Using Combobox to retrieve data from MS SQL DataBase and fill a textbox with the data

I am working on a VB.Net project in Visual Studio 2013 project. I want a combobox to retrieve data from ms access database and fill a textbox

I have a MS Access DB Named DataDB and i have a Form Named Form1 with a Combobox on it is Named *cboData* and three textBox Named txtName, txtPhone and txtAddress. The DataDB holds my customer Name, Phone and Address.

I want to use the ComboBox to access the DataDB and use the value to populate three textBox Named txtName, txtPhone and txtAddress in the form(load event)

Comment: What have you tried? have you read [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's important that you learn how to break a problem down into smaller parts. Retrieving data from a database is completely unrelated to `ComboBoxes` and `TextBoxes` so you should treat it as such. Retrieving filtered data from a database is the same regardless of where the filter values comes from or where the data goes to. Learn how to retrieve data first, then learn how to filter the data you retrieve, then simply plug the appropriate data from your `ComboBox into that already working code. Not breaking a problem into parts is a big reason that beginners can't find relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear what your motive is.But as far as i think,u want to populate a combo box from an access database(maybe).Then you can try this

```
'create a connection string named con

Public sub MyForm_Load

Dim cmd as new OleDbCommand("Select * from [table name here-avoid brackets 
 if required]",con)

Dim adapter as new OleDbDataadapter(cmd)

Dim table as new datatable

adapter.fill(table)

ComboBox1.DataSource = table
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = table.Columns(3).ToString 'you can use column name or even row
```

Now, to add text to the textbox from the combo box, try :

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_IndexChanged

Textbox1.tex=Combobox1.text
```

If you think this is not what you want, then please clarify your needs

**Datatable to textbox**

```
 For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        textbox1.Text = table.Rows(i)(3).value.ToString
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks a million. So now how do i get colunm 4 from my table to my textbox 4 , and colunm 5 to textbox 5 all from the same combobox when the selection is made.

Comment: easy... in datagridview cell content click, add this : textbox4.text=dgvw1.currentrow.cells(3).value

Comment: please upvote the comments and mark the answer as answer

Comment: I still Do not get you. can you add it up to the code

Comment: Please I don Understand you.

Comment: okey...just gve me your row and column number/name, i will update the code

Comment: The Table in the data Base is Sale, The table is PRODUCTS and Colunm are Product_Name, Price1, Price2, Price3 and Stock. To be fill into textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 When the The selection is made from the ComboBox1

Comment: can u please explain a bit more

Comment: can u please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have A Data bass Name Sale That I created In Assess, It has a table in it called PRODUCT. Each Product has and ID, Name, Price1, Price2, Price3 and Stock.

Comment: 3 persons - John,Derby,Jack.They have AGE,SALLARY,HEIGHT.The names will be in a COMBO BOX.From the combo box, if someone selects JOHN, the other 3 textboxes will show his AGE,HEIGHT,SALLARY.If someone selects Jack from the combobox,the textboxes will show jack's height,sallary,age----Is this simillar to waht you want ?

Comment: Yes. This what i want. you understand me. But all the data should be pulled from a Access data base.

Comment: Well, it's gonna be a messy code and might slow down the application, do u still want to use this method?

Comment: Yes I still need it.